# Similarity between idioms

Tags: idioms

Would you please say if the  following idioms imply the same meaning?
1- Let's get down to brass tacks.
2- Let's cut to the chase.

Comment: Please look up the two idioms and, if you still have a question, edit your question to tell  us what you don't understand.  For example, when I Google "cut to the chase", I get [this entry](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cut+to+the+chase) in The Free Dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think they are quite the same. Getting down to brass tacks implies drilling down into the details of a situation, especially those which make the whole thing work. Cutting to the chase is a little different because it implies a removal of a lot of noise and the elimination of unecessary steps.

Getting down to brass tacks could be a lengthy analytical process whereas cutting to the chase is associated with the opposite.

Comment: Your answer would benefit from some sources that support your conclusions. Otherwise it is just an opinion...and belongs in the comment section.

Answer (score 1):

The idiom "Cut to the chase" was born in Hollywood and refers to film scripts. Pitching their scripts to producers, writers, as is their nature, might dwell on such aspects of their stories as character, theme and plot, which many producers view as negligible. The producer knows that only the big scene--frequently a literal chase scene--will put butts in seats, so that's the scene he wants to hear about. Cut out all the literary bullshit and give me action.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_to_the_chase

There are several explanations for the origin of "getting down to brass tacks," but they are all similar in that they involve the uncovering of something essential to the repair of a piece of furniture or taking an accurate measurement. The idiom could be substituted for "let's get to the bottom line," basically what is the final cost of a project or just what a project will entail.

http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/get-down-to-brass-tacks.html

A Hollywood producer would not use the idioms interchangeably. He would use "chase," with writers, but he would use "brass tacks" with directors in an effort to find out how much the masterpiece will cost to make.

However, the meanings do overlap enough so that someone buying a used car might use either in trying to get a slippery salesperson to quote him a price.

Comment: Could you add some reputable links so we can verify this?